# Primefaces blockUI stops responding

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable and a commandbutton. I want to use blockui when user either clicks to datatable paginators or refresh button. At first blockui works with paginators good but after when I click to commandbutton, blockui works once and then it stops working. Is there any idea?

```
<p:commandButton value="refreshDatatable" 
                                 id="refreshLogListButtonId2"
                                 onclick="loading.show();"
                                 oncomplete="loading.hide();"
                                 immediate="true"                                 
                                 update="logsTableId"
                                 icon="ui-icon-refresh"
                                 actionListener="#{logViewerController.refreshLogsFromDB()}"/>


<p:dataTable id="logsTableId" var="log"....../>

<p:blockUI block="logsTableId" trigger="logsTableId" widgetVar="loading">  
            Refreshing<br />
            <p:graphicImage library="images" name="loading.gif"/>  
        </p:blockUI>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the id of your  in the trigger attribute of the  separated by ",", like that:

```
<p:blockUI block="logsTableId" trigger="logsTableId,refreshLogListButtonId2" widgetVar="loading">  
    Refreshing<br />
    <p:graphicImage library="images" name="loading.gif"/>  
</p:blockUI>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not update blockUI component. Use either the trigger attribute or the widgetVar, there is no reason to use both.